# How to do a grep to match one line with an offset in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep, offset

I want to get a one line grep result in a for loop and pass to the next match without all the other matches from before.

I tried the code below but it's not working as expected as I want only one line result.
$nbOfMatches=7
$className=somefile

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 $nbOfMatches);
do
    lineCopy=$(grep -m $i 'private ' $className)
    echo "$lineCopy"
done
```

Current output :

```sh
Occurences found : 7
private $id;
private $id;
private $firstname;
private $id;
private $firstname;
private $lastname;
private $id;
private $firstname;
private $lastname;
private $email;
private $id;
private $firstname;
private $lastname;
private $email;
private $password;
private $id;
private $firstname;
private $lastname;
private $email;
private $password;
private $phone;
private $id;
private $firstname;
private $lastname;
private $email;
private $password;
private $phone;
private $address;
```

Expected output :

```sh
Occurences found : 7
private $id;
private $firstname;
private $lastname;
private $email;
private $password;
private $phone;
private $address;
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to add a offset match to the grep to remove the previous match from being detected too. Or if there is any other solution to do the expected output.

Comment: I think you can do what you want without a loop, but I don't understand what you want. Something like `grep 'private ' "$className" | sort -u | head -7`?

Comment: Try directly without loop: `grep 'private' ${className} | uniq`

Comment: What I'd like to do is get every variable like ``` $firstname,... ``` on one line and remove the private property and the semi-colon to get only the variable name "firstname" or "email"... in a array or a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple one liner to do the trick. This will also produce the same results:

```
nbOfMatches=4;grep -m$nbOfMatches private $className
```

Also to print the string between `$ ... ;` you can use the sed. `sed 's/.* $\(.*\);/\1/'`

```
nbOfMatches=4;grep -m$nbOfMatches private $className | sed 's/.* $\(.*\);/\1/'
```

Below is a lengthy solution (if loop is mandatory). There are much elegant ways to achieve the same result.

```
className="input.txt"; nbOfMatches=4; count=0; for next in `cat $className`; do var=$(echo $next | awk /private/'{print $0}'); if [ $nbOfMatches -eq $count ]; then break; fi; if [ ! -z "$var" ]; then echo "$var"; let count=$((count + 1)); fi; done
```

This reads the specified file `$className` line by line and search for the pattern `private`. For each match it will increment the variable `count`. When the `count` becomes number of matches`$nbOfMatches` needed, it exit from the loop.

Also to print the string between `$ ... ;`.

```
className="input.txt"; nbOfMatches=4; count=0; for next in `cat $className`; do var=$(echo $next | awk /private/'{print $0}'); if [ $nbOfMatches -eq $count ]; then break; fi; if [ ! -z "$var" ]; then echo "$var"| sed 's/.* $\(.*\);/\1/'; let count=$((count + 1)); fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Get every variable like `$firstname,...` on one line and remove the private property and the semi-colon to get only the variable name "firstname" or "email"...
When you always have one space after private you can use

```
grep 'private ' "$className" | sort -u | sed -rn '1,7 s/private \$([^;]*);/\1/p'
```

or shorter (when fields are unique in a file)

```
 sed -rn 's/private \$([^;]*);/\1/p' "$className" | head -7
```